# vue js array with one object-element

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
  <span> {{ item.name }} </span>
  {{ item.brand.logo }}
</div>
```

There is an array items, it stores one element of the form (brand):
[{"link": "/ shop", "logo": "123.jpg"}]

But, if I ask for item.brand.logo, nothing is displayed. How should you refer to the logo in order to display a picture?

Items: [ {id: 12345, name: name, brand: [{ link: link, logo: logo }]} ]

Comment: It's `item.brand[0].logo`

Answer (score 0):

This is more an `HTML` question than actually `VueJS`. Since we don't know (you didn't include an example) of how exactly your `items` object looks like I will assume that you are traversing it correctly.

You can simply use `<img src="src"/>` to display the image.

```
<div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
 {{ item.brand }}
 <img :src="item.brand.logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: items is main array.
And items have different elements, like image, price, BRAND (as i said, brand seems like {"link": "/ shop", "logo": "123.jpg"}])
And i dont know, how to show Logo from object brand

Comment: If the `brand` is as you said you should have the image being rendered in `img` tag. One thing I forgot to say, you need to pass the *FULL URL* (e.g. https://my-website.com/123.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your brand is an array, so I would take:

```
{{ item.brand[0]?.logo }}
```